# I have to find homography transform parameters which are 8 in number with the help on CNN

Tags: python, keras, cnn, prediction

I have to find homography transform parameters which are 8 in number..I m using a pretrained residual network. The problem I am facing is I am not able to use model.fit() as it takes argument such as x-train and labels and I don't have any labels. In dataset only stable and unstable videos given?